# Selecting polygons over raster extent using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I would like to select all the polygons that are within my raster extent.

Is there a tool in QGIS to do it ?

Such as the select by location tool but instead of comparing the features from another vector doing it with the raster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Select Features by Expression` tool, with this expression:

```
within($geometry, layer_property( 'raster name', 'extent'))
```

Notes:

- Substitute the name of your raster name where the expression says 'raster name'
- The two layers must be in the same coordinate reference system